# Using spring-boot-starter dependency on a non boot project, Is a good practice?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

lets say that I need to develop a not boot app to develop an application that uses *redis cache* to store and retrive data.

I can use the *spring-boot-starter* dependency instead adding multiple dependencies, and it is working fine.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now my question..
Is it a good practice to add spring-boot-starter dependency on a non boot project?

Comment: Why can't you just try?

Comment: @StanislavL I tried it is working. Is that a best practice? I just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just keep in mind that it will bring some transitive dependencies into your project, like `org.springframework.spring-{context,beans,core,tx,...}`.